# Muxless hybrid graphic card and power-saving

Tags: ati, power-management, battery, hybrid-graphics

I have a laptop with hybrid Intel/AMD graphics. As far as I know, the configuration is muxless. This causes not-detection of discrete graphic card. And now my problem: I don/t know how to turn the discrete card completely off. I think it is powered all the time, because of critically short battery work time(approx. 3 hours instead of windows 7-8). Tlp and adjusting the brightness do not bring expected effect. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: what distro of linux do you have? is it ubuntu? which version?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer:

[How to disable the discrete AMD graphics card in Linux](http://planetoss.com/articles/how-to-disable-the-discrete-amd-graphics-card-in-linux/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.